# How define subtitle color in mencoder?

Tags: video, subtitles, mencoder

I use this command on Ubuntu to burn subtitle to video:

```
mencoder mysub.mp4  -sub myvideo.srt -subcp utf8 -subfont-text-scale 3  -subfont-outline 2   -font ~/.mplayer/sans-bold.ttf  -ovc xvid -oac mp3lame -xvidencopts pass=1 -o output-video.avi
```

It works fine but I also like to assing color to the fonts. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

**COUPLE OPTIONS**

1. `-ass-color <value>`

For the `ass-color <value>` it's excepting the `RRGGBBAA` format specifically. Here's a color picker site link in this format: http://peteroupc.github.io/colorpicker/demo.html

> Sets the color for text subtitles. The color format is RRGGBBAA.
>
> Alpha Color Picker (RRGGBBAA format)

2. `-sub-bg-color <0-255>`

**MENCODER**

http://linux.die.net/man/1/mencoder